# Is there a natural problem on the naturals that is NP-complete?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, nt.number-theory, combinatorial-game-theory

Any natural number can be regarded as a bit sequence, so inputting a natural number is the same as inputting a 0-1 sequence, so NP-complete problems with natural inputs obviously exist. But are there any natural problems, i.e. ones that do not use some encoding and special interpretation of the digits? For example "Is n a prime?" is such a natural problem, but this one is in P. Or "Who wins the Nim game with heaps of size 3, 5, n, n?" is another problem that I consider natural, but we also know this to be in P. I am also interested in other complexity classes instead of NP.

Update: As pointed out by Emil Jeřábek, given $a,b,c\in \mathbb N,$ to determine whether $ax^2+by-c=0$ has a solution over the naturals is NP-complete. This is exactly what I had in mind as natural, except that here the input is three numbers instead of just one.

Update 2: And after more than four years waiting, Dan Brumleve has given a "better" solution - note that it's still not complete because of the randomized reduction.

Comment: I know of a NEXP-complete tiling problem where the input is an integer n and the problem is to determine if there exists a valid tiling of an n x n grid. If that's interesting to you, I'll look for the paper.

Comment: What about problems like subset sum? The input is a set of integers, similar to your nim example.

Comment: I’m rather confused by your comment replying to yourself, but should I take it to mean you only allow a single number as the input? I’d think Manders–Adleman is a quite natural problem.

Comment: the word "natural" is used all over CS and resists strict defn.... there is a problem listed in Garey & Johnson relating to modulo arithmetic....

Comment: @Emil: domotorp's comment was a response to a confusion I had. But it was a misunderstanding on my part so I deleted the comment. I think the input is required to be  a single natural number, which should not encode anything.

Comment: @Emil: What is Manders-Adleman? I have found many papers by them and some problems that take two integers as inputs. Ps. I have deleted my old comment.

Comment: @Robin: Yes, I would be very much interested in the NEXP-complete tiling thing.

Comment: @Evgenij: I want the input to be only one integer, similar to my nim example.

Comment: @vzn: Yes, I know natural has no mathematical definition. I use it to mean that n should not encode anything. If the G&J problem fits, then I would be interested in it.

Comment: @domotorp: The NP-complete problem I meant is, given $a,b,c\in\mathbb N$, determine whether $ax^2+by-c=0$ has a solution $x,y\in\mathbb N$. Another variant is, given $a,b,c$, determine whether there is $x\le c$ such that $x^2\equiv a\pmod b$. (The result is from http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/800113.803627 .)

Comment: @emil in my memory that is also the one in Garey-Johnson. worthy of an answer imho

Comment: Why isn't the answer to this question obviously **NO**?  Every NP-hard problem has instances that "encode" a boolean circuit; arguably, that's what being NP-hard means!

Comment: have the same issue but think there is a real question here if someone asks for the "simplest" NP-complete number theory problem. which poster didnt in the question, but did apply that tag. on the other hand, answers that make a good case for some POV on what "natural" constitutes seem close too. the word "natural" shows up in many CS papers but is defined often informally & based on context...

Comment: @JɛﬀE: I think the idea is that the encoding should be completely incidental to the problem itself; that it stands on its own as a 'simple' (as opposed to 'easy') problem about natural numbers which one might plausibly ask without even being aware of the SAT problem.

Comment: @domotorp: perhaps another good "natural" candidate is the problem of finding the minimum addition chains of a single given number $n$: from [On the Number of Minimal Addition Chains](http://ww1.ucmss.com/books/LFS/CSREA2006/CSC4596.pdf): "... The problem of finding a minimal addition chain for a set of $m$ numbers is NP-complete. This does not imply as it is sometimes claimed that finding a minimal addition chain for $n$ is NP-complete. However, we can easily deduce that
the problem of finding all minimal addition chains for
a number $n$ is NP-complete ..."

Comment: similar question/answers on mathoverflow here [Number theory and NP-complete](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/72628/number-theory-and-np-complete)

Comment: thx, vzn for the link!

Answer (score 35):

Based on the discussion, I’ll repost this as an answer.

As proved by [Manders and Adleman](http://dx.doi.org/10.1145/800113.803627), the following problem is NP-complete: given natural numbers $a,b,c$, determine whether there exists a natural number $x\le c$ such that $x^2\equiv a\pmod b$.

The problem can be equivalently stated as follows: given $b,c\in\mathbb N$, determine whether the quadratic $x^2+by-c=0$ has a solution $x,y\in\mathbb N$.

(The original paper states the problem with $ax^2+by-c$, but it is not hard to see that one can reduce it to the case $a=1$.)

Comment: This is a great example. Something surprising to me: this problem basically asks: “Is $a$ a small quadratic residue mod $b$, i.e. is it a square of some $0 < x \le c$?” If I understand correctly, finding several small quadratic residues mod $N$ is precisely how factoring algorithms work (quadratic sieve, CFRAC, etc), and factoring is not believed to be NP-complete. So it seems that the best algorithms for factoring are based on solving a (presumably easy instance of an) NP-complete problem!

Answer (score 10):

Here's a  $\text{NEXP}$-complete problem with a single natural number as the input.

The problem is about tiling an $n \times n$ grid with a fixed set of tiles and constraints on adjacent tiles and tiles on the boundary. All of this is part of the specification of the problem; it is not part of the input.  The input is only the number $n$. The problem is  $\text{NEXP}$-complete for some choice of tiling rules as shown in

> D. Gottesman, S. Irani, "The Quantum and Classical Complexity of Translationally Invariant Tiling and Hamiltonian Problems," Proc. 50th Annual Symp. on Foundations of Computer Science, 95-104 (2009), [DOI: 10.1109/FOCS.2009.22](http://dx.doi.org/10.1109/FOCS.2009.22). Also [arXiv:0905.2419](http://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2419).

The problem is defined on page 5 of the arxiv version.

Additionally, they also define a similar problem that is $\text{QMA}_\text{EXP}$-complete, which is the bounded-error quantum analog of $\text{NEXP}$. (The classical bounded error analog of $\text{NEXP}$ is $\text{MA}_\text{EXP}$.)

Comment: +1, but it's a little hard to argue that the number $n$ is being used in a "natural" way, since it is encoding the input to a particular Turing machine (specifically, the tiling exists iff the Turing machine accepts $x$, where $x$ is the $n$-th in an enumeration of potential input strings).  Still a very interesting result.

Comment: I maximally agree with mjqxxxx.

Answer (score 2):

I think that using one of the time-bounded variants of Kolmogorov complexity you can build a problem that uses only the binary representation of a number and (I think) is unlikely to be in $\mathsf{P}$; informally it is a decidable version of the problem "Is $n$ compressible?":

Problem: Given $n$, does a Turing machine $M$ exist such that $|M| < l$ and $M$ on a blank tape outputs $n$ in less than $l^2$ steps, where $l = \lceil \log{n} \rceil$ is the length of the binary representation of $n$

It is clearly in $\mathsf{NP}$, because given $n$ and $M$, just simulate $M$ for $l^2$ steps and  if it halts compare the result with $n$.

Comment: I think this problem is quite TM based but of course it is impossible to draw a line.

Comment: To refine domotorp's comment, I would say that the fact that it has to invoke the notion of a Turing machine at all in the problem description rules it out as a 'natural problem about natural numbers'. (If we suppose that a ntaural problem about natural numbers is one whose general format would be consistent *e.g.* with Fermat having studied it, without supposing too counterfactual a history of mathematics.)

Answer (score 2):

Our [FOCS'17 paper](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/hard_presburger3.pdf) on the Short Presburger Arithmetic is an example of a "natural" problem which is NP-c, and uses a constant number $C$ of integers in the input, say $C< 220$.  It is different from Manders-Adleman in that the constraints are all inequalities.  See Gil Kalai's [blog post](https://gilkalai.wordpress.com/2019/03/22/danny-nguyen-and-igor-pak-presburger-arithmetic-problem-solved/) for some background.

Comment: I think this is more natural than Manders-Adleman. Is smaller than $5$ variables and $10$ inequality example possible?

Comment: No, 5 variables is the smallest.  10 - not sure.  But you can't really have less than 6...

Comment: Is there a reason behind $\geq5$ and $\geq6$? I mean is it proven that all $\leq4$ and finite number of inequalities is in $P$ (likewise all $\leq5$ variables and $\leq5$ inequalities formulation is in $P$?)?

Comment: Yes.  For fewer variables the problem is in P.

Comment: Is a reference available for this claim?

Comment: Yes.  It's all in our paper and Danny Nguyen's thesis.  http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/Nguyen-thesis.pdf

Answer (score 1):

How about the [PARTITION problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem)?

Comment: No, as the input is not a number but a set.

Comment: So are you asking for problems for which an instance is exactly one natural number? I don't think that's clear in your question, as you ask for "problems with natural inputs" and your example of the Nim game involves four numbers.

Comment: I am sorry if I was vague in the formulation of the question.