# Is prime-counting function #P-complete?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, counting-complexity, nt.number-theory, comp-number-theory, primes

Recall $\pi(n)$ the number of primes $\le n$ is the [prime-counting function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function).  By "PRIMES in P", computing $\pi(n)$ is in #P.  Is the problem #P-complete?  Or, perhaps, there is a complexity reason to believe that this problem is not #P-complete?

P.S.  I realize this is a bit naive since somebody must have studied the problem and proved/disproved/conjectured this, but I can't seem to find the answer in the literature.  See [here](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~pak/papers/ICM-paper9.pdf) if you are curious why I care.

Comment: I think a BQP algorithm may solve this problem. we know how to factoring a number with a BQP‌ algorithm and I think these problems are same but I don't know how to reducing this problem to factoring at these moment!(it is just a gues) #P-Complete is a very large complexity class and It is unlikely that BQP  to have #P-Complete problems.

Comment: @MohsenGhorbani: Nope, not the "same" problems.  Not even similar.

Comment: Not evidence against, just curious: do we know a single function $f(n)$ that is #P-complete that really treats n as a number? That is, we can always look at the binary representation of n and treat that binary string as a SAT formula or graph, but I want to avoid that.

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow The "natural" (not NT) hard problems I know with one parameter are all in #EXP-c.  An example of such problem: number of tilings of $n \times n$ square with a fixed set $T$ of tiles (i.e. the tiles are not in the input).  Thm: there exists $T$ s.t. this problem is #EXP-c.

Comment: @Joshua This is quite related to NP-completeness of $f(n)$, for which, apparently, we also don't have a definite answer yet: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/14124/is-there-a-natural-problem-on-the-naturals-that-is-np-complete

Comment: Notice that $\mathrm{\#P^{BPP}=\#P}$, hence $\pi$ was in #P ever since Miller–Rabin.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek:  I did not know that.  Is this a standard textbook result?

Comment: Yes, this is a standard result. It comes from Köbler, Schöning, Toda & Torán, "Turing machines with few accepting computations and low sets for PP".

Comment: Sorry, what I wrote is not quite correct. It’s true that $\mathrm{PP^{BPP}=PP}$, but for #P, we only get a reduction: if $f\in\#\mathrm{P^{BPP}}$, there is $g\in\#\mathrm P$ and a polynomial $p$ such that $f(w)=\lfloor g(w)2^{-p(|w|)}\rfloor$ ($|w|$ being the length of the input $w$).

Answer (score 2):

Some heuristic evidence: to the best of our knowledge  $\pi(n)$ looks like a simple function corrected by random fluctuations.  Thus I’d expect a poly-time machine with a $\pi(n)$ oracle to be no stronger than such a machine with a random oracle, and w.r.t. a random oracle $X$ adding a separate random oracle $Y$ to $\mathsf{P}$ gives $\#\mathsf{P}^X \not\subset \mathsf{P}^{XY}$ with probability 1 (here $Y$ corresponds to $\pi(n)$ and $X$ is an independent random oracle).

Comment: I find the last sentence misleading. While indeed $\Pr_X[\mathrm{PP}^X\ne\mathrm{P}^X]=1$, what we actually need here is $\Pr_X[\mathrm{PP}\nsubseteq\mathrm{P}^X]=1$, and we do not know if this is true. In fact, this is equivalent to $\mathrm{PP\ne BPP}$.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Sure, but in terms of evidence that $\pi(n)$ isn't #P-complete, if one could show formally that if it's #P-complete then PP=BPP, I'd take that as pretty strong evidence against #P-completeness...

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow I agree with that. I just don’t think the result on $\mathrm P^X\ne\mathrm{PP}^X$ with random oracle is relevant.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek: Yep, that’s a good point.  Before I edit, would you accept as evidence the fact that $P^{XY} \ne \#P^X$ a.a. given two random oracles, which I think we do know?

Comment: Do we know that?

Comment: We know that $\mathsf{BPP} < \mathsf{NP}$ w.r.t. a random oracle (according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BPP_(complexity)), and presumably the same proof gives $\mathsf{P}^{XY} \ne \mathsf{NP}^X$.